# How to save Many To Many field with Multiple Checkboxes in Django Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I would like to know how in the following form `color` (many-to-many field) can be populated by values from `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget.

**#models.py**

```
class Color(models.Model):
    RED = 1
    BLACK = 2

    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (RED, _('Red')),
        (BLACK, _('Black')),
    )

    name = models.CharField(_('Color'), max_length=512,
                        choices=COLOR_CHOICES, blank=True)
class Car(models.Model):
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Color, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Car, self).save()
```

**#forms.py**

```
class AddCar(forms.ModelForm):
    color = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=Color.COLOR_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        required=False
    )
```

**#view.py**

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddCar(request.POST)
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
            car = form.save(commit=False)

            for c in request.POST.getlist('color'):
                car.color.add(c)

            car.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            return redirect('/')
```

**#error**

```
'Car' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you not getting the checkboxes to show, or is it the error you're trying to get rid of? If the latter, try removing the `commit=False` when saving the form.

Update:
The `Color` model is not specifying any fields. Give it one, e.g. `color = IntegerField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES)`.

In `AddCar` form, giving `choices=Color.COLOR_CHOICES` if wrong - you must give it a tuple of objects that actually exists (Color.COLOR_CHOICES are just code constants). Also you probably should use ModelMultipleChoiceField, which takes a `queryset` parameter, e.g.:

`colors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Color.objects, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

Comment: The checkboxes are displaying, I am getting the selected values in the view but I can't save them. After removing commit=False I get this error: insert or update on table "cars_car_color" violates foreign key constraint

Answer (score 4):

You are doing `form.save(commit=False)` in which does not actually creates record in DB and due to which it cannot store M2M fields. Do `form.save_m2m()` after you save form.

Or from your code, you can move `car.color.add()` after you have saved the `car`. And also you don't need to have `form.save(commit=False)`.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because, you are trying to save related objects to an object that isnt saved, 
you are two options:

put `commit=True`

or before:

```
for c in request.POST.getlist('color'):
                car.color.add(c)
```

put:   `car.save()`

If you use `commit=False`, that objects is not beign saved.

But, you dont need save manually the "colors",
doing `form.save_m2m()` will do it for you, well, only if your form has
a manytomany field to choise.

EDIT:

Your color field within form, isnt well formed, must be a ModelMultipleChoiceField

```
color = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Color.objects.all())
```

see docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: I tried commit=True which resulted in "violates foreign key constraint"

Comment: Your color field within form, isnt well formed, must be a ModelMultipleChoiceField

color = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Color.objects.all())


https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets